# Better way than multiple SELECT statements?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, common-table-expression, postgresql-performance

I'm creating a web app that displays a pie chart. In order to get all the data for the chart from a **PostgreSQL 9.3** database in a single HTTP request, I'm combining multiple `SELECT` statements with `UNION ALL` — here's a portion:

```
SELECT 'spf' as type, COUNT(*)
    FROM (SELECT cai.id
          FROM common_activityinstance cai
          JOIN common_activityinstance_settings cais ON cai.id = cais.activityinstance_id
          JOIN common_activitysetting cas ON cas.id = cais.id
          JOIN quizzes_quiz q ON q.id = cai.activity_id
          WHERE cai.end_time::date = '2015-09-12'
          AND q.name != 'Exit Ticket Quiz'
          AND cai.activity_type = 'QZ'
          AND (cas.key = 'disable_student_nav' AND cas.value = 'True'
            OR cas.key = 'pacing' AND cas.value = 'student')
          GROUP BY cai.id
          HAVING COUNT(cai.id) = 2) sub
UNION ALL
SELECT 'spn' as type, COUNT(*)
    FROM common_activityinstance cai
    JOIN common_activityinstance_settings cais ON cai.id = cais.activityinstance_id
    JOIN common_activitysetting cas ON cas.id = cais.id
    WHERE cai.end_time::date = '2015-09-12'
    AND cai.activity_type = 'QZ'
    AND cas.key = 'disable_student_nav'
    AND cas.value = 'False'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'tp' as type, COUNT(*)
    FROM (SELECT cai.id 
          FROM common_activityinstance cai
          JOIN common_activityinstance_settings cais ON cai.id = cais.activityinstance_id
          JOIN common_activitysetting cas ON cas.id = cais.id
          WHERE cai.end_time::date = '2015-09-12'
          AND cai.activity_type = 'QZ'
          AND cas.key = 'pacing' AND cas.value = 'teacher') sub;
```

This produces a nice, small response for sending back to the client:

```
 type |  count 
------+---------
 spf  |  100153
 spn  |   96402
 tp   |   84211
```

I wonder if my queries can be made more efficient. Each SELECT statement uses mostly the same JOIN operations. Is there a way to not repeat the JOIN for each new SELECT?
And I would actually prefer a single row with 3 columns.

Or, in general, is there some entirely different but better approach than what I'm doing?

Comment: Common table expression may be your way to go.

Comment: If you don't provide table definitions like you should you *must* at least table-qualify *all* columns in the query or we have no chance to know where columns come from. And do you need the result as 3 rows or can it be a single row with three columns?

Comment: Thanks. They're qualified now (`cas.key` and `cas.value`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bundle most of the cost in a single main query in a [CTE](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/queries-with.html) and reuse the result several times.
This returns a **single row with three columns** named after each `type` ([as requested in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32544322/postgresql-9-3-better-way-than-multiple-select-statements/32545083#comment52946781_32544322)):

```
WITH cte AS (
   SELECT cai.id, cai.activity_id, cas.key, cas.value
   FROM   common_activityinstance cai
   JOIN   common_activityinstance_settings s ON s.activityinstance_id = cai.id
   JOIN   common_activitysetting cas ON cas.id = s.id
   WHERE  cai.end_time::date = '2015-09-12'   -- problem?
   AND    cai.activity_type = 'QZ'
   AND   (cas.key = 'disable_student_nav' AND cas.value IN ('True', 'False') OR
          cas.key = 'pacing' AND cas.value IN ('student', 'teacher'))
   )
SELECT *
FROM  (
   SELECT count(*) AS spf
   FROM  (
      SELECT c.id
      FROM   cte c
      JOIN   quizzes_quiz q ON q.id = c.activity_id
      WHERE  q.name <> 'Exit Ticket Quiz'
      AND   (c.key, c.value) IN (('disable_student_nav', 'True')
                               , ('pacing', 'student'))
      GROUP  BY 1
      HAVING count(*) = 2
      ) sub
   ) spf
,  (
   SELECT count(key = 'disable_student_nav' AND value = 'False' OR NULL) AS spn
        , count(key = 'pacing' AND value = 'teacher' OR NULL) AS tp
   FROM   cte
   ) spn_tp;
```

Should work for Postgres 9.3. In Postgres 9.4 you can use the new aggregate `FILTER` clause:

```
  count(*) FILTER (WHERE key = 'disable_student_nav' AND value = 'False') AS spn
, count(*) FILTER (WHERE key = 'pacing' AND value = 'teacher') AS tp
```

Details for both syntax variants:

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

The condition marked `problem?` may be big performance problem, depending on the data type of `cai.end_time`. For one, it's not [**sargable**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable). And if it's a `timestamptz` type, the expression is hard to index, because the result depends on the current time zone setting of the session - which can also lead to different results when executed in different time zones.

Compare:

- [Sustract two queries from same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28422763/sustract-two-queries-from-same-table/28423238#28423238)
- [Subtract hours from the now() function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30894296/subtract-hours-from-the-now-function/30896121#30896121)
- [Ignoring timezones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-timezones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)

You just have to name the time zone that is supposed to define your date. Taking my time zone in Vienna as example:

```
WHERE  cai.end_time >= '2015-09-12 0:0'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna' 
AND    cai.end_time <  '2015-09-13 0:0'::timestamp AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Vienna'
```

You can provide simple `timestamptz` values as well. You could even just:

```
WHERE  cai.end_time >= '2015-09-12'::date
AND    cai.end_time <  '2015-09-12'::date + 1
```

But the first variant does not depend on the current time zone setting.
Detailed explanation in the links above.

Now the query can use your index and should be much faster if there are many different days in your table.

Comment: Thanks for the incredibly thorough response; however, this is returning a 0 in each column.

Comment: @AlienBishop: I think I found the problem. I had misread `cais.id` as `cai.id`.

Comment: Also had to change `s` to `cais` in the first `JOIN`. It's working now, and it's about a 3x performance improvement on average.

Comment: @AlienBishop: Nice. It can probably be even faster if you resolve the `problem?` part.

Comment: We do have a btree index on `cai.end_time`, but it is a `timestamp with time zone` type. I'll have to research whether we can change its type.

Comment: @AlienBishop: you don't have to change the type. I'll add a solution.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a sketch of a completely different approach: construct a boolean "hypercube" for all conditions that you need
in your "crosstabulation". the logic of selecting or aggregating subsets can be done later (such as suppressing the exit_tickets, for which the business logic is not clear to me)

---

```
SELECT DISTINCT not_exit, disabled, pacing
    , COUNT(*) AS the_count
    FROM (SELECT DISTINCT cai.id
          , EXISTS (SELECT *
            FROM quizzes_quiz q 
            WHERE q.id = cai.activity_id AND q.name != 'Exit Ticket Quiz'
            ) AS not_exit
          , EXISTS ( SELECT *
            FROM common_activityinstance_settings cais  
            JOIN common_activitysetting cas ON cas.id = cais.id
            WHERE cai.id = cais.activityinstance_id
            AND cas.key = 'disable_student_nav' AND cas.value = 'True'
            ) AS disabled
          , EXISTS ( SELECT *
            FROM common_activityinstance_settings cais 
            JOIN common_activitysetting cas ON cas.id = cais.id
            WHERE cai.id = cais.activityinstance_id
            AND cas.key = 'pacing' AND cas.value = 'student')
            ) AS pacing
          FROM common_activityinstance cai
          WHERE cai.end_time::date = '2015-09-12' AND cai.activity_type = 'QZ'
    ) my_cube
GROUP BY 1,2,3
ORDER BY 1,2,3
  ;
```

---

Final note: This method is based on my *assumption* that the underlying data model is in fact an EAV-model, and that an attribute can occur at most once per student.

Comment: `EXISTS` works subtly different than a `JOIN` in that it folds multiple matches in `quizzes_quiz` on the same `cai.activity_id` into one. Depending on the undisclosed data model and the intention behind the query this may be wrong or irrelevant or even what the OP really wants. The column name `id` implies 1:1 in this case, so `EXISTS` should basically work - but it looks like you missed the special case of `HAVING COUNT(cai.id) = 2`, which requires *two* steps of aggregation.

Comment: There was insufficient information available about the data model. My (premature) conclusion is that this is an EAV-like model, and the OP wants to count (the number of persons with) occurences of  attributes (disabled = 'false') or (pacing = 'student' ) or both. (IMHO, the *both* case was the intention of the COUNT(*) = 2 in the original query)

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter , that was.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial answer.  The second two can be combined into one query:

```
SELECT (case when key = 'disable_student_nav' then 'spn' 
             when key = 'pacing' then 'tp'
        end) as type, COUNT(*)
FROM common_activityinstance cai JOIN
     common_activityinstance_settings cais
     ON cai.id = cais.activityinstance_id JOIN
     common_activitysetting cas
     ON cas.id = cais.id
WHERE cai.end_time::date = '2015-09-12' AND cai.activity_type = 'QZ' AND
      (key, value) in (('disable_student_nav', 'False'), ('pacing', 'teacher'))
GROUP BY type
```

I wonder if there is a way to put the first group into similar logic.  For instance, if the `QZ` condition could be applied to all three groups, then adding in the first group would be easy.

Comment: Thanks. This looks like it might be a good alternative. Regarding the first group, the `QZ` condition is applied to all three in my original queries, so how would you add the first group?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `case` with the conditions in your `where` clause for each type. However, the first query's `having` condition would not be satisfied by this.

```
select type, count(*) as count
from
(
SELECT cai.id,
case when q.name!= 'Exit Ticket Quiz' and key = 'disable_student_nav' 
AND value = 'True' OR key = 'pacing' AND value = 'student' then 'spf'
     when key = 'disable_student_nav' AND value = 'False' then 'spn'
     when key = 'pacing' AND value = 'teacher' then 'tp'
 end as type
      FROM common_activityinstance cai
      JOIN common_activityinstance_settings cais ON cai.id = cais.activityinstance_id
      JOIN common_activitysetting cas ON cas.id = cais.id
      JOIN quizzes_quiz q ON q.id = cai.activity_id
      WHERE cai.end_time::date = '2015-09-12'
      AND q.name != 'Exit Ticket Quiz'
      AND cai.activity_type = 'QZ'
) t
group by type
```

Answer (score -1):

There's no way to make that query much more efficient, no.  You could set up a view or whatever, but it'll always have to run through it three times.  But you could solve the problem by doing some post-processing in PHP or PL/SQL or whatever.  Start with a simpler query, something like this:

SELECT COUNT(*), cai.id, q.name, key, value
      FROM common_activityinstance cai
      JOIN common_activityinstance_settings cais ON cai.id = cais.activityinstance_id
      JOIN common_activitysetting cas ON cas.id = cais.id
      WHERE cai.end_time::date = '2015-09-12'
      GROUP BY cai.id, q.name, key, value

...I'm not clear from your explanation whether this would result in a reasonable number of output rows.  But assuming it does, write a little code to massage them into the shape you want.

Comment: My original query was taking about 8 seconds. The query in the accepted answer executes in a fraction of a second.